# Trouble of a MySql query not returning the right information

Tags: mysql, database

This is the query I have already:

```
use willkara;

select EngagementNumber,AgentID, EntertainerID, StartDate, EndDate, ContractPrice, ContractPrice/DateDiff(EndDate,StartDate) AS PricePerDay 
FROM EA_Engagements 
where StartDate <= '1999-8-13' 
  and EndDate   >= '1999-8-8'
ORDER BY EngagementNumber;
```

And this is the problem:

I need a list of engagements that occurred between 8/8/1999 and 8/13/1999. I only want to see the engagements that started on or after 8/8/1999 and ended on or before 8/13/1999. For each of those engagements, I need to know how long (in days) the engagement was, and the IDs of the entertainer and the agent, and the contract price per day of entertainment. Remember, when we compute the length of an engagement, we include both the day it started and the day it ended. Please sort the information in Engagement number order. [2 rows]

8 columns needed; Last column must be labeled PricePerDay

For some reason, some of the end dates are 8-15 and 8-19 and it's only suppose to be the dates that end on the 13th.

Comment: By any chance... do you happen to have your columns switched? `StartDate <= '1999-8-13' and EndDate >= '1999-8-8'` be `EndDate <= '1999-8-13' StartDate and >= '1999-8-8'` or maybe I'm missing something..

Answer (score 0):

Since they are two fields, it would be theoretically possible for someone to put in a start date that's older than the end date and vice versa leading to incorrect results.  I'd adjust your query accordingly, do a between or something similar.